# Samsung 7 active, #*#*4636#*#*?

Tags: samsung

[image][image]Hello when putting this code into the phone dialer ,under the usage time ,is that total time used or just that time?anyone know,thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The usage time is the total time when the app is/was in the foreground; meaning the total time when you are/were interacting with an app. When the app is in the background, although in use (for example, a music app), that time is not included in the total time under "usage time".

Comment: Thanks that was a important  question, but how do I know the time frame for this time used ?instead of total

Comment: @TinaHopkins Can you re-frame the question? I don't understand this part "the time frame for this time used" because time is used many times :)

Comment: Hello thanks for responding ,but honest I am not gonna waste my time or yours on something I know is true  .my other is hiding shit ,I have been a fool long enough ,making excuses for stuff on his phone that he doesn't know how lol,so thanks again ,wish me luck .regardless the pain of a break up was my last choice

Comment: I tried to upload a pic to further explain but it want load

Comment: This should explain why I choose to let it go but if it helps I was referring  to the second pic on the time used